# Why TYPO3 throws a missing service error after composer installation?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a TYPO3 V10 composer installation.

After a composer update I got this message in frontend:

> (1/1) Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException
> Cannot autowire service
> "TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Utility\InstallUtility": argument
> "$lateBootService" of method "injectLateBootService()" references
> class "TYPO3\CMS\Install\Service\LateBootService" but no such service
> exists.

and in the install tool that message:

> (1/1) #1519978105 TYPO3\CMS\Core\DependencyInjection\NotFoundException
> Container entry "TYPO3\CMS\Install\Http\Application" is not available.

I have tried to remove the vendor, TYPO3 and extentions folder and did a fresh composer installation with:

```
composer install
composer dump-autoload -o
```

My composer.json is not special:

```
{   "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "Distribution V10",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "deployer/deployer": "^6.8",
        "deployer/recipes": "^6.2",
        "fluidtypo3/vhs": "^6.0",
        "georgringer/news": "^8.3",
        "gridelementsteam/gridelements": "^10",
        "helhum/config-loader": "^0.12.2",
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^6.3",
        "in2code/powermail": "^8.1.1",
        "jambagecom/static-info-tables-de": "^6.7",
        "plan2net/webp": "^3.1",
        "sgalinski/sg-cookie-optin": "^3.1",
        "t3/dce": "^2.5.2",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-dashboard": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-indexed-search": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-install": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-linkvalidator": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-opendocs": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-recordlist": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-recycler": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-scheduler": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^10.4"
    },
     "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Ikiu\\TYPO3\\Distribution\\": "build/src",
            "Ikiu\\Theme\\":"public/typo3conf/ext/theme/Classes"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cweiske/php-sqllint": "^0.2.3",
        "helmich/typo3-typoscript-lint": "^2.1",
        "rector/rector": "^0.7.2"
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: According your post it seems your are not able to login to the install tool. So instead of removing the DI cache via cache clearing in the install tool try to delete it manually, delete the folder var/cache/code/di

Comment: I found that Bug https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91446 wich look like this.

Comment: It seems that the autoloader path is missing. Did you try to include the config and extra attributes in the composer.json? Something like that? http://prntscr.com/ul3w24

Answer (score 4):

For unknown reason the install system extension did vanish from the typo3conf/PackageStates.php file.
Simply add the config for the install extension to the file.

```
    'install' => [
        'packagePath' => 'typo3/sysext/install/',
    ],
```